# Is it possible to prove the time a message was produced?

Tags: protocol-design, provable-security, zero-knowledge-proofs

Say Bob wants to tell Alice a secret message, then they start some message exchanges protocol. At the end, Alice will receive the secret message and can be convinced that the message was not produced earlier (and obviously not later) than the time they communicated.

An attacker (Bob included) will try to win by forging the secret message before they start the message exchanges.

As for a real world scenario, consider the secret message a picture, showing something of Alice's interest. Bob sends this picture to Alice, Alice however, doubt the picture was taken a long time ago, so she challenges Bob to send as well some random angles of the things showing in the picture as she requested until she is convinced that the things showing in the picture are there at the time they communicate. Note that the things in the picture can be there a long time ago (e.g. an old house) , but the secret message (the picture showing the old house) was only produced at that moment.

The security of the above scenario is only based on Bob not knowing the random choice of the angles Alice will pick and the infeasibility of Bob quickly creating a fake picture at the said angle. Can cryptography provide something better than these?

Somehow I believe the "infeasibility to create variants of the secret message" is a must assumption to guarantee the proofs. So may be in real world this cannot be a simple plaintext message, but sound, picture, video, 3D model, etc., which are difficult to edit?

Comment: I have no experience in the issue you described. But I think perhaps the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp could be of  some interest to you.

Comment: @Mok-KongShen Yes sure. A timestamp in a form that is unpredictable yet decipherable to tell the exact time. Problem is how can this timestamp be incorporated into the message so that it cannot be removed or changed.

Answer (score 2):

If the the message is generate by a one-way function then incorporating in the message a sample from a randomness beacon (such as https://www.nist.gov/programs-projects/nist-randomness-beacon) will prove that the message was generated at a time later than when the sample was taken.

Comment: Are you aware of the legal position regarding such a beacon?  Could it be used to provide an incontestable alibi when I'm accused of robbing a bank for example?  Or for proof of prior art in a patent?  Or is it just a geeky novelty toy?

Comment: @stromboli Thank you for letting us know such devices. Proving the message was generated later than the beacon together with an online interactive protocol surly can prove the message generation time in that exact moment. Do you think there can also be a way to do so with an offline non-interactive protocol? Like the message was prepared first and send later but still the time it was generated can still be proved?

Comment: @PaulUszak It is definitely not a toy but a service that the NIST provides based on needs. I don't see how it can serve as alibi since you can obtain samples retroactively. I also don't think it is relevant for proof of prior art because the beacon lets you prove you did something *after* some time whereas in prior art you want to prove that it *predates* a given time. The main use of the beacon though, I believe, is when a multiple-party needs a neutral, shared source of randomness for all parties.

Comment: @user1589188 You can prove the generation time in an offline protocol if you use a trusted third party to timestamp the message, for example a camera that has built-in timestamping and which has been audited to prove it wasn't tampered with.

Comment: @stromboli Yes, that means the security is based on the tamper resistance property of the device. I am more hoping a cryptographic way.

Comment: @user1589188 Well whenever you use public key cryptography you assume for example that the private key is not accessible. When you're issued with a smartcard it is assumed you won't tamper with it. It all depends on the attack vector. In the next comment I'll show you a cryptography clock device that you cannot forge, but it relies on the device's processor speed.

Comment: @user1589188 Lets invent a device which, given a seed, continuously computes its hash, that hash of the hash, and so on. Since the device' processor has a finite speed, the hash iteration that it achieved indicates a minimal timestap that, if the seed was kept secret (or e.g., it was appended with a secret value stored in the device), cannot be forged. Now the receiving party initializes the device with a random seed and it starts running. The sending party stamps the photo with the hash iteration $n$ at the time the photo was taken, and thus can prove that the time was no earlier than $t(n)$.

Comment: @user1589188 In the same vein as a camera, is an HSM (hardware security module). However unlike (most?) cameras an HSM is specifically designed to be tamper resistant. They are used by banks and other institutions that need a high level of assurance. Additionally the HSM can sign messages and keep the private key confidential - again with a high level of assurance. BTW, the OP could be improved by specifying you want an offline method and if you have cost or other constraints, what they are.

Comment: @stromboli I guess it is not the time source the issue in this scenario, it is the stamping process. A picture can be taken long ago but stamped only when Alice requests a proof. So no argue the nonce has to be incorporated into the picture at the time it was generated. And it seems the only way to enforce this is a tamper resistant device. As if saying a software unhackable that always print the time on the photo it takes. Nothing really "crypto" here dont you think?

Comment: @user1589188 Define picture... Nowadays it is something generated by imaging software based on samples from a sensor. I can't see how you can trust a digital picture without trusting either the device or its operator.